# Simulator IPad pro (works) vs iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have my mobile app in Objective C. 
I have a scroll view page. In Simulator iPad Pro it works.
In Simulator iPhone 6 Plus, the scroll view starts at lower part of
page and I cannot get it back up to top. In fact all of
the iPhone ( 5,6,7) look like the iPhone 6 plus.ie the top of
the page shows "Grade" and "County". I cannot scroll up to see 
"First Name". The only thing I am changing is the device.

Suggestions?

[image: ipad pro]

below is iPhone 6 Plus

[image: iphone 6 plus]

Comment: Are you using auto-layout and constraints? Are you laying out all the elements in a Storyboard, or adding them via code?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED- During trying all several options, I
forgot I had:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
// REMOVE the LINES BELOW
[self.scroller layoutIfNeeded];  
 self.scroller.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
  self.contentView.center = self.view.superview.center;
```

}

After removing the 3 lines above, it worked correctly in iPhone 5, 6, 7.
The IPad worked WITH or WITHOUT those 3 lines.
I spent a lot of time on this. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score -1):

are you using Constraints to setup your views? if so then try checking scrollview's top constraint whether its linked to Top Layout Guide's bottom ?

[image]

Comment: I do use Constraints. I will look into that.